# Trying to Setup Android Project using .bat to replace text in .xml files

Tags: text, batch-file, replace

I am trying to setup android projects. This is a quick and easy way to do it, so all I have to do is import the final code into eclipse and export it. I use a base source code for all my projects and all I have to do is just change the app title and package name and new drawables and I have another app, However my .bat script looks like this.

```
@echo off
rmdir /s /q "%~dp0out"
mkdir out
xcopy "%~dp0other\backup" "%~dp0out" /E > nul
java -version 
if errorlevel 1 goto errjava
cls
echo.
PAUSE
echo.
echo packagae name 
echo whats your packagename after cube3d.packagename
echo. 
set /P INPUT=Enter: %=%
echo.
echo App Name 
echo whats your App name before Live Wallpaper
echo. 
set /P INPUT2=Enter: %=%
echo.
echo Airpush App ID
echo What is the 6 digit airpush app id
echo. 
set /P INPUT3=Enter: %=%

copy "%~dp0placeimages" "%~dp0out\res\drawable"
rename out\src\cube3d\aaaaapnzme %INPUT%

call run2.bat
call run3.bat
call run4.bat
```

It will run and go to run2.bat and stop after. it doesn't do run3.bat afterwards it fails to go to the 3rd and then the 4th. This is what the other bats look like.

run2.bat looks like this and this one works perfectly.

```
rep "aaaaapnzme" "%INPUT%" out\src\cube3d\%INPUT%\*.java out\AndroidManifest.xml out\src\cube3d\%INPUT%\objects\*.java
```

that's as far as the script will go and it fails to go to run3.bat and then to run4.bat

run3.bat looks like this

```
rep "zapsname" "%INPUT2%" out\res\values\strings.xml
```

run4.bat looks like this

```
rep "aeropush" "%INPUT3%" out\AndroidManifest.xml
```

I am using Windows 8 Pro if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

What is `rep` ?

perhaps `CALL rep...` would fix the problem.

Comment: rep replaces the name using a program called rep.exe

Comment: Also tried adding in call before rep, it still does the same thing as before.

Comment: Hmm are you sure that there's no other `rep` executable on the path - a `rep.bat` perhaps? coould you replace `rep` with the full-filename for the `rep` executable - quoted if necessary - and see whether that makes any difference?

Comment: I get same thing when I put call rep.exe im wondering if its a windows 8 issue so ima try on a windows 7 pc later